# mysql docker container - cannot connect with windows

Tags: mysql, docker, windows-10

I am very sorry guys, I found several topics on stackoverflow but none of them solved my issue. I am a docker noob, but all I want to do is connect to my docker mysql database in a docker container created via docker-desktop on windows.

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name blaaa -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql
```

I set up everything with the suggested port mapping, but I cannot connect to the docker container from the host (windows 10) via mysql-workbench or other programs. I read that there are issues and you often cannot connect to the docker host via localhost, but I cannot even figure out what the freakin ip of docker0 or other adapters is (ipconfig does not show anything). `docker inspect <id>` shows a lot of information, but besides mapping to 0.0.0.0:3306 and other ips that don't work, I cannot really figure out what to do here. the container itself is running fine and I can access the database from inside the container without any issues.

thanks for your help!

/**SOLVED**

I am sorry for the confusion; I think it was due to the Windows clients (I tried several) that things didn't work out. I finally got it working with HeidiSQL. Don't ask me how or why HeidiSQL finally works; but mysql-workbench generally showed strange behavior on my system, it crashed several times out of the blue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name use this to get ip of container

Comment: thanks for your answer. I actually get the ip, but I still cannot connect...

Comment: do I understand this correctly that the logs should at least log something if there is a service from outside trying to connect? because they do not mention anything... I am just trying to figure out if this problem is related to the container or maybe mysql-workbench...

Comment: how did you try to connect to the container?

Comment: are you sure the container is running? try `docker ps`  tell us the result

Comment: @antoniomerlin You cannot access the Docker-private IP addresses on Windows or MacOS hosts, or if you're not on the same physical host, or if a VM is involved, or ....  You shouldn't ever need to look them up.

Comment: @DavidMaze kk, i only  put that snippet above as in question there is docker inspect <id>

Comment: thanks for your help. yes, the container is running fine as I said. I can exec into it etc. also using wsl mysql works, but mysql-workbench and other windows clients don't. I'll stick to wsl then for setting up the tables, which is fine. however, I am asking myself if other programs built under windows (for instance, with java spring) will then be able to connect to this database if I cannot even find it under windows...

Comment: You cant connect from container in wsl to windows man 

Answer (score 0):

Hey when you don't specify the database name, the container will stop as soon as it created, so specify the database name as environment variable

this is the docker command :

`docker run -p <host_machine_port>:3306 --name <container_name> -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<root_password> -e MYSQL_DATABASE=<db_name> -d mysql`

in your case :`docker run -p 3306:3306 --name blaaa -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE= testDB -d MySQL`

And next verify if the container running or not: `docker ps` 
if it shows the container name you specified when you created it, it's running.

next connect to your container : `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -u root -p password`

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I am not sure if you really need to define a database first... the container seems to be running fine without any initial db. Yet, you are right that the mysql repo on Docker Hub mentions problems [when not initializing a db first](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). However, I cannot access the db via windows even if I set up an initial database... WSL works fine, however.

Comment: Can you show me thr docker ps result after command i sughested to you ans how can u connect to database without a name ??

Comment: Oh man did.you run the docker containers on wsl and trying to access in windows ?? 

Comment: Docker Desktop on Windows is based on WSL 2.0. By the way, I tried running containers both with and without defining a mysql_database, both are running fine. But you are right, this might be the issue... since docker desktop seems to be based on wsl, maybe this causes the issue. sorry, I simply have no real clue of how this whole thing works under windows. But I can access other web applications running in containers as well via localhost on windows. Maybe it's really more a problem with mysql-workbench... or I am messing up somewhere else (which is very likely, too).

Comment: I never used the doxker desktop so i really dont know whats happenig but if i find a solution i will let you know 

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d -p 3307:3306 mysql
```

reason explained here -p is an argument

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/504